# SharePoint 2013 On Premise Apps Configuration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

In our farm, we have 5 WFEs, 4 Application servers, we are trying to enable apps in our farm, for which the domain has been configured using the steps mentioned in the TechNet article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx

I have two queries regarding this for the SharePoint configuration aspect :

1. It is mentioned in the article that two services have to be started via App Management service and the SharePoint Foundation subscription settings service. Should these two services be started in all the servers across the farm or only in Selected servers?
2. Will this have an impact on the RAM usage, in that should we have a certain amount of free RAM available for these two services to be enabled, since in our Wfes we noticed that there was only 20% free RAM?

Looking forward to your responses. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those two services should be spun up on all servers in the farm per the streamlined topology model.

As with anything, yes there will be an impact on memory usage. How much depends on your usage of Apps. This is something you will want to continually measure; there is no definitive number we can provide to you.